# Powershell : getting memberships and the number of members of the group

Tags: powershell

If the number of members of the group is less than 3 I want to export those members like below.
by the way , there are nested groups too.

My desired output:

```
Members,Group Name,Members Count,Members
NO,Group01,10
NO,Group02,1,user01
YES,Group03,2,user01;user02
```

Here is my script :

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\tmp\unused.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $out = @{ 'Group Name' = $_.Name }
    if((Get-ADGroup $_.Name -Properties Member).Member) {
        $out['Members'] = 'YES'
    }
    else {
        $out['Members'] = 'NO'
    }
    [pscustomobject] $out
} | Export-Csv "C:\tmp\export.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Oops soory I forgot that. I have accepted my previous question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the expected result, note that `Get-ADGroupMember` will return all members recursively for each group, if this is not what you want, remove the `-Recursive` parameter.

Also note, this may return any object class as member of the group (computers, other groups, users, service accounts...), you want to only target **Users** as members, use the following:

```
$members = @(Get-ADGroupMember $_.Name -Recursive).where{ $_.objectClass -eq 'user' }
```

**Code**

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\tmp\unused.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $out = [ordered]@{
        'HasMembers'    = ''
        'Group Name'    = $_.Name
        'Members Count' = ''
        'Members'       = ''
    }
    # using `-Recursive` since there can be nested groups
    $members = @(Get-ADGroupMember $_.Name -Recursive)
    # if count is 0
    if(-not $members.Count) {
        $out['HasMembers'] = 'NO'
    }
    # if count is lower than 3 and greater than 0
    elseif($members.Count -lt 3) {
        $out['HasMembers'] = 'YES'
        $out['Members'] = $members.Name -join ';'
    }
    # if count is greater than 2
    else {
        $out['HasMembers'] = 'YES'
    }
    $out['Members Count'] = $members.Count
    [pscustomobject] $out
} | Export-Csv "C:\tmp\export.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```